# c# propertygrid convert from uint to string

Tags: c#, .net, propertygrid

I can't convert showing property from `uint` to `string` format in `PropertyGrid` control. This is what I do:

```
var fruits = new SortedDictionary<uint, string>
{
   {0, "Apple"},
   {1, "Orange"},
   {3, "Watermelon"},
};

public class FruitConverter : StringConverter
{
   public override bool CanConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, 
                                       Type sourceType)
   {
      if (sourceType == typeof(uint) && fruits.ContainsKey(sourceType))
         return true;

      return base.CanConvertFrom(context, sourceType);
   }

   public override object ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, 
                                     CultureInfo culture, 
                                     object value)
   {
       if (sourceType == typeof(uint) && fruits.ContainsKey(sourceType))
           return fruits[value];

       return base.ConvertFrom(context, culture, value);
    }
}

public class Fruit
{
    [ReadOnly(true)]
    [DisplayName("Type of fruit")]
    [TypeConverter(typeof(FruitConverter))]
    public uint FruitTypeCode { get; set; }
}
```

But property `FruitTypeCode` is still is shown as `uint` and not as a `string`, what I did wrong ?

Comment: Your code wont compile.  Did you mean for `fruits` to be a property on `FruitConverter`?  Also, `sourceType` is not a paramter on `ConvertFrom`.

Comment: try inheriting from TypeConverter instead of StringConverter

Comment: the example in msdn is pretty much close to what you want to achieve. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ayybcxe5(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
public class FruitConverter : TypeConverter
{
    public override object ConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value, Type destinationType)
    {
        return fruits[(uint)value];
    }
}
```

Comment: That works. Thanks a lot. Should I implement `CanConvertTo()` method ? Or what if `fruits` dictionary doesn't contain `(uint)value`

Comment: If the converter has a really localized usage (like only for this property for example), it's not really necessary, but if you plan to use it widely, yes, you should implement CanConvertTo and also check the destinationType is a string.